# disable max-lines-per-function on certain function **names**

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm using ESLint's [`max-lines-per-function`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-lines-per-function) to make sure I refactor in time. My React components' `render` function almost always exceed my 25 lines and I was wondering, besides adding a disable comment, if there was a way to disable an ESLint rule for certain function **names** (such as `render`)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an ESLint plugin [eslint-plugin-react-func](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-func). It also has a rule called `max-lines-per-function`, but this rule will skip any function that contains JSX element

```sh
 npm i eslint-plugin-react-func -D
```

or

```sh
 yarn add eslint-plugin-react-func -D
```

In your .eslintrc.* file

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "react-func/max-lines-per-function": [
      "warn",
        {
          "max": 25,
          "skipBlankLines": true,
          "skipComments": true,
          "IIFEs": true
        }
     ],
  },
    "plugins": ["react-func"]
}
```